# How to create JSON object in php without key name?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, indexing

I am trying to create JSON Object and array in php. but It creates unwanted indexes (keys).Is there any way I can create object without Key name like $temp_obj-> No Key here $all_products_array; ???? Thanks in advance

This is How am I trying...

```
$combo_info = new stdClass();
$combo_info-> combo_id = $combo_id;
$combo_info-> combo_name = $combo_name;

$temp_obj = new stdClass();
for($i=0; $i<=16; $i++){
    $all_products_array = array();
    $all_products_array = array("product_id" => $product_id,"product_name" => $product_name);
    $temp_obj->all_products_array_inside[$i] = $all_products_array;
}

$myObj = new stdClass();
$myObj->combo_info = $combo_info;
$myObj->all_products_array = $temp_obj;
$myfinalobj-> myfinalobj[$i] = $myObj;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo '['. json_encode($myfinalobj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) .']';
```

It will produce below result where index/key named "1" and "all_products_array_inside" are unwanted. Because I have to go myfinalobl->all_products_array->all_products_array_inside[1].product_id
but i want easy like myfinalobl->all_products_array[i].product_id

> Is there any way I can create object without Key name like
>   $temp_obj-> **No Key here** $all_products_array; **????**

```
{
    "myfinalobj": {
        "1": {
            "combo_info": {
                "combo_id": "1",
                "combo_name": "Supper_deal",
            },
            "all_products_array": {
                "all_products_array_inside": {
                    "1": {
                        "product_id": "1",
                        "product_name": "TV"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "product_id": "2",
                        "product_name": "Laptop"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the key yourself (from `$i`), so just don't do that...

```php
$myfinalobj->myfinalobj[$i] = $myObj;
```

Here you have `[$i]` - remove it:

```php
$myfinalobj->myfinalobj = $myObj;
```

Comment: I don't need index at all for some object so that how it should look like? $temp_obj->  $all_products_array;  <- like this ??

Comment: without the second `$` though, otherwise you'd say to use the _contents_ of the `$all_products_array` variable as key name.

Comment: Let's assume `$test = 'abc'; $obj = new stdClass();`. After you write `$obj->test = 123';` you will have the `test` property of `$obj` set to `123`. After you write `$obj->$test = 123;` (note the second `$`!), you will have the _`abc`_ property of `$obj` set to `123`, because you are not specifying a key named `test` but instead a key named after the _contents_ of the variable `$test`, which is `abc`. Hence you probably don't want the second `$` there.

Comment: What if i don't want key name at all? Only value? Is it possible?

Comment: That's not logical. Under what name would you access it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214983/discussion-between-priyank-patadiya-and-cherrydt).